# calculate normal field of cylinder and sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

in a book it is given that the unit normal field  of $S^2$ is $N(p)=p$ the identity map.

pictorially it is clear to me. But if I take any point  on the sphere and multiply(usual scalar product of vectors) to N(p) then it must be 0.
My question is how should I do this calculations.

as for example:-

Let S = {$(x, y, 0)| x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}$} be the $xy$ plane in $R^3$. Then
$N(x, y, 0) = (0, 0, 1)$ is a constant unit normal field on S as  their inner product is 0.

How can I calculate similar thing for sphere and cylinder.

Comment: Do you mean the scalar product of a point on your sphere/cylinder multiplied by the vector to a neighbor point?

Comment: no want to multiply scalar product of a point on your sphere/cylinder multiplied by the vector on the normal

Comment: But this is in general not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Given a regular surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and a point $p\in S$, the normal unit vector at $p$ is orthogonal to *the tangent plane to $S$ at $p$*.

One of the ways to define the tangent plane, is the set of all possible derivatives of paths in $S$, that pass through $p$ at time $0$:

$T_pS:=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^3|\exists \alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to S, \alpha(0)=p, \dot{\alpha}(0)=v\}$.

The example $S=\{(x,y,0)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ has the special property that for any $p\in S$, $T_pS=S$. Most surfaces don't have this property (Q:What is the set of surfaces that do?). In the sphere, for example, this equality does not hold. The fact that the unit normal vector at $p$ is equal to $p$, may be expressed in terms of the tangent plane as:

$\forall p\in S^2\quad T_pS^2=p^\bot$.

In terms of paths and their derivatives, the above is equivalent to the following fact:

For any smooth (or differentiable) $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to S^2$ such that $\alpha(0)=p$, the derivative of $\alpha$ satisfies $<\dot{\alpha}(0),p>=0$, where $<\cdot,\cdot>$ is the standard inner product.

Try and prove this statement, it's a nice and not too hard exercise.

As for the cylinder, or any other surface, you should try first to find an expression for the tangent plane at any point.